# example on divisor of a plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I am trying to understand this example on the use of divisor of a curve:

Let $C$ be the projective plane curve with homogeneous equation $Y^2Z=X^3$. Let $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$ . Then one has $k(C)=k(x, y)/(y^2-x^3)$, and
$div_C(x)=2[P]-2[\infty]$ and $div_C(y)=3[P]-3[\infty]$, where $P$ is the point $(0,0,1)\in C$
and $\infty =(0,1,0)$. If $U$ denotes the plane curve $C\setminus\{\infty\}$, then $div_U(x) = 2[P]$ and
$div_U(y) = 3[P]$.

Can anybody help me understand why $div_C(x)=2[P]-2[\infty]$ and $div_C(y)=3[P]-3[\infty]$, where $P$ is the point $(0,0,1)\in C$
and $\infty =(0,1,0)$?

Comment: Can you show that $X/Y$ is a local parameter at $\infty$ and $Y/X$ is a local parameter at $P$? A point is that $Y/X=y/x$ is integral over the coordinate ring $k[x,y]$ and therefore belongs to the local ring of $P$.

Comment: How did you calculate $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord} \ord_P(x)=2$ and $\ord_P(y)=3$?  $C$ is singular at $P$, so the local ring $k[C]_P$ is not a discrete valuation ring.